# Custom 2D/3D Graphics Vector Classes vs SFML's

Tags: c++, computational-geometry

I don't really like SFML's Vector Classes so I tried making my own. Any criticism is welcome.

```
    class gVector2{
    public:
        float x, y;
        float length = GetLength();
        gVector2();
        gVector2(float X, float Y) : x(X), y(Y){};
        float GetLength(){ return sqrtf((x * x) + (y * y)); }
        void Normalize(){ x /= length, y /= length; }
        float Dot(gVector2 rightVec){ return (x * rightVec.x) + (y * rightVec.y); }

        gVector2 operator+ (gVector2);
        gVector2 operator- (gVector2);
        gVector2 operator* (float);
        gVector2 operator/ (float);
        void operator+= (gVector2);
        void operator-= (gVector2);
        void operator*= (float);
        void operator/= (float);
        void operator= (gVector2);
        bool operator== (gVector2);
        bool operator!= (gVector2);
};

gVector2::gVector2(){
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
}

gVector2 gVector2::operator+(gVector2 rightVec){
    gVector2 solution;
    solution.x = x + rightVec.x;
    solution.y = y + rightVec.y;
    return solution;
}

gVector2 gVector2::operator-(gVector2 rightVec){
    gVector2 solution;
    solution.x = x - rightVec.x;
    solution.y = y - rightVec.y;
    return solution;
}

gVector2 gVector2::operator*(float scalar){
    gVector2 solution;
    solution.x = x * scalar;
    solution.y = y * scalar;
    return solution;
}

gVector2 gVector2::operator/(float scalar){
    gVector2 solution;
    solution.x = x / scalar;
    solution.y = y / scalar;
    return solution;
}

void gVector2::operator+=(gVector2 rightVec){
    x += rightVec.x;
    y += rightVec.y;
}

void gVector2::operator-=(gVector2 rightVec){
    x -= rightVec.x;
    y -= rightVec.y;
}

void gVector2::operator*=(float scalar){
    x *= scalar;
    y *= scalar;
}

void gVector2::operator/=(float scalar){
    x /= scalar;
    y /= scalar;
}

void gVector2::operator=(gVector2 rightVec){
    x = rightVec.x;
    y = rightVec.y;
}

bool gVector2::operator==(gVector2 rightVec){
    if (x == rightVec.x &&
        y == rightVec.y)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool gVector2::operator!=(gVector2 rightVec){
    if (x != rightVec.x ||
        y != rightVec.y)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

class gVector3{
public:
    float x, y, z;
    float length = GetLength();
    gVector3();
    gVector3(float X, float Y, float Z) : x(X), y(Y), z(Z) {};

    float GetLength(){ return sqrtf((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z)); }
    void Normalize(){ x /= length, y /= length, z /= length; }
    float Dot(gVector3 rightVec){ return (x * rightVec.x) + (y * rightVec.y) + (z * rightVec.z); }
    gVector3 Cross(gVector3);

    gVector3 operator+ (gVector3);
    gVector3 operator- (gVector3);
    gVector3 operator* (float);
    gVector3 operator/ (float);
    void operator+= (gVector3);
    void operator-= (gVector3);
    void operator*= (float);
    void operator/= (float);
    void operator= (gVector3);
    bool operator== (gVector3);
    bool operator!= (gVector3);


};

gVector3::gVector3(){
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    z = 0;
}

gVector3 gVector3::Cross(gVector3 rightVec){
    gVector3 crossProduct;
    crossProduct.x = (y * rightVec.z) - (z * rightVec.y);
    crossProduct.y = (z * rightVec.x) - (x * rightVec.z);
    crossProduct.z = (x * rightVec.y) - (y * rightVec.x);
    return crossProduct;
}

gVector3 gVector3::operator+(gVector3 rightVec){
    gVector3 solution;
    solution.x = x + rightVec.x;
    solution.y = y + rightVec.y;
    solution.z = z + rightVec.z;
    return solution;
}

gVector3 gVector3::operator-(gVector3 rightVec){
    gVector3 solution;
    solution.x = x - rightVec.x;
    solution.y = y - rightVec.y;
    solution.z = z - rightVec.z;
    return solution;
}

gVector3 gVector3::operator*(float scalar){
    gVector3 solution;
    solution.x = x * scalar;
    solution.y = y * scalar;
    solution.z = z * scalar;
    return solution;
}

gVector3 gVector3::operator/(float scalar){
    gVector3 solution;
    solution.x = x / scalar;
    solution.y = y / scalar;
    solution.z = z / scalar;
    return solution;
}

void gVector3::operator+=(gVector3 rightVec){
    x += rightVec.x;
    y += rightVec.y;
    z += rightVec.z;
}

void gVector3::operator-=(gVector3 rightVec){
    x -= rightVec.x;
    y -= rightVec.y;
    z -= rightVec.z;
}

void gVector3::operator*=(float scalar){
    x *= scalar;
    y *= scalar;
    z *= scalar;
}

void gVector3::operator/=(float scalar){
    x /= scalar;
    y /= scalar;
    z /= scalar;
}

void gVector3::operator=(gVector3 rightVec){
    x = rightVec.x;
    y = rightVec.y;
    z = rightVec.z;
}

bool gVector3::operator==(gVector3 rightVec){
    if(x == rightVec.x &&
       y == rightVec.y &&
       z == rightVec.z)
    {return true;
    }else{
    return false;
    }
}

bool gVector3::operator!=(gVector3 rightVec){
    if (x != rightVec.x ||
        y != rightVec.y ||
        z != rightVec.z)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: *I'll separate it into a header and cpp file when I have some more time to work on it.* I would recommend waiting to post a question on SE when you have time.  If a question requires feedback from you at the start, and you're not around, it may pose a problem.  If you don't have time to help the reviewers, then they may not have enough time to help you.

Comment: Okay, but as you're new here, I should tell you that reviewers are allowed to comment on any aspect of the code.  They may assume that this is how it's structured locally, and review on that anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it stands, your code has quite a few issues. 
Since you are familiar with SFML's vector classes, I suggest taking a look
at the library to get some ideas from a well established codebase before 
starting your own. Also, [see this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62764/c-3d-vector-implementation) for a very similar Vector implementation review.

OK, onto the review:

**Problems with the operators:**

All these operators are incorrect:

```
void operator+= (gVector2);
void operator-= (gVector2);
void operator*= (float);
void operator/= (float);
void operator= (gVector2);
```

Same goes for `gVector3`. They were supposed to return a reference
to the type you are manipulating. This allows composing expressions
like you would do with an integer, for example. The correct signature is:

```
gVector2 & operator+= (gVector2);
gVector2 & operator-= (gVector2);
gVector2 & operator*= (float);
gVector2 & operator/= (float);
gVector2 & operator= (gVector2);
```

Returning `*this` in the implementation.

---

The comparison operators for both `gVector2` and `gVector3`

```
bool operator== (gVector2);
bool operator!= (gVector2);
```

Should be made `const`, since they are not altering member state:

```
bool operator== (const gVector2 &) const;
bool operator!= (const gVector2 &) const;
```

Also, in this case, it is probably better to take the input parameter
by const ref, instead of by value.

These should also be const:

```
gVector2 operator+ (gVector2) const;
gVector2 operator- (gVector2) const;
gVector2 operator* (float) const;
gVector2 operator/ (float) const;
```

But they return by value since each will produce a new vector, so this is correct.

```
float GetLength() const
float Dot(gVector2 rightVec) const;
```

Any member function that does not mutate class data should be make const. This is a good practice.

**Storing `length` as a member:**

This seems like a major design flaw to me. Once the vector is
constructed it sets the `length` member, but as soon as someone
changes any of the elements of the vector, `length` is no longer valid.
You shouldn't keep that member variable at all. The `GetLength()` method is there
so that the user can get a "fresh" length whenever is necessary.

BTW, `gVector3::Normalize()` will produce wrong results if `length` is not up-to-date.

**Miscellaneous:**

`sqrtf()` is not standard. Instead, include `<cmath>` and use `std::sqrt()`.

---

In the implementation of all the operators, it would be a lot better and more efficient
to construct the returned object in-place, instead of having those local variables:

```
gVector2 gVector2::operator - (gVector2 rightVec) 
{
    return gVector2(x - rightVec.x, y - rightVec.y);
}
// The same for all the others...
```

---

You have inconsistent/mixed `{` positioning on the `if`s:

```
if (x == rightVec.x &&
    y == rightVec.y)
{
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
```

Either use all like this:

```
if (x) {
    do_x();
}
else {
    do_y();
}
```

Or all like this:

```
if (x) 
{
    do_x();
}
else 
{
    do_y();
}
```

---

In the comparison operators, there is a much more concise way of doing the checks:

```
bool gVector2::operator == (const gVector2 & rightVec) const 
{
    return (x == rightVec.x && y == rightVec.y);    
}
```

No need for the `if` chains at all!